# Most applications won't open, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, steam

I open an application with the terminal and then the icon of the application pops up and pulses, but then nothing happens.

With all of the research I have done so far I think there is a problem with the drivers. I have 7700k and gtx 1070, and I assume the problem is coming from this. I have the most recent drivers from nvidia (378.13), and also from Intel.

When I try to run steam the icon just pulses the terminal output is:

```
$ steam

Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
Generating new string page texture 12: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49.15 KB
Generating new string page texture 13: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311.30 KB
Generating new string page texture 14: 128x256, total string texture memory is 442.37 KB
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 769
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561197960265728 [API loaded no]
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
[0216/052858:ERROR:web_plugin_impl.cc(38)] Widevine registration is not supported after context initialization
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1484790260)
```

Other applications seem to be running as well, but nothing shows up.

I have tried to reinstall the drivers multiple times, rebooting, reinstalling steam, but nothing. 
I have also tried `kbl_huc` ver2 (problems in between gpu and cpu?) that installed successfully but hasn't changed anything.

Comment: How many monitors do you have attached to your system?

Comment: … and what's the output of `xrandr`?

Comment: Just one monitor.

Comment: xradnr output: $ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)